# Is mule 3.3.2 compatible with open JDK 1.6?

Tags: java, groovy, mule

We am having an issue with mule 3.3.2, groovy 1.8.6 (and 2.1.3), and open JDK.  After switching from JDK 1.6 to OpenJDK 1.6 we got this exception. I also trying groovy 2,1.3 with OpenJDK 1.7.

Anyone have an ideas?  Is OpenJDK combatable with groovy?

GC

```
[12-18 11:26:34] ERROR CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy [[field-core-composite-1.8-SNAPSHOT-v20181217-16+40].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.07]: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Scripting engine 'groovy' not found.  Available engines are: []
Type                  : org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/InitialisationException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Scripting engine 'groovy' not found.  Available engines are: [] (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
  org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable:107 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/InitialisationException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Scripting engine 'groovy' not found.  Available engines are: []
               at org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable.initialise(Scriptable.java:107)
               at org.mule.module.scripting.expression.AbstractScriptExpressionEvaluator.getScript(AbstractScriptExpressionEvaluator.java:82)
               at org.mule.module.scripting.expression.AbstractScriptExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(AbstractScriptExpressionEvaluator.java:54)
               at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:311)
               at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:230)
               at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager$1.match(DefaultExpressionManager.java:460)
               at org.mule.util.TemplateParser.parse(TemplateParser.java:153)
               at org.mule.util.TemplateParser.parse(TemplateParser.java:130)
               at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.parse(DefaultExpressionManager.java:456)
               at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.parse(DefaultExpressionManager.java:430)
               at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer.evaluateTransformParameter(XsltTransformer.java:494)
               at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer.doTransform(XsltTransformer.java:237)
               at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer.transformMessage(XsltTransformer.java:182)
               at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:145)
               at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:93)
               at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1455)
               at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1363)
               at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1341)
               at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1333)
               at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.process(AbstractTransformer.java:123)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:46)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
               at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:46)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
               at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:46)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
               at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:102)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:46)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:46)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
               at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:194)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:46)
               at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
               at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
               at o...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users have reported success with JVMs from Oracle (Sun), JRockit, IBM, and OpenJDK.

You must also install JDK6, as explained below.

https://docs.archive.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.3/hardware-and-software-requirements#java